# How to create all possible permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

there is a problem:

I have 5 letters - a,b,c,d,e and 20 places. I have to use each letter at least once but no more than 10 times. So the result can look like {a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,c,d,e},... etc.
I need to find all possibilities.

I was trying something like this:

```
    With[{n = 5, k = 20}, Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[s, {k}, Range[n]], {s, k, n k}]]
```

And then changing numbers to letters. Then I can delete cases where there is no a,b,c,d or e and also cases with more than 10 same letters.

But I would prefer a solution, where I don't have to delete these cases but I can set conditions before evaluation.
Thanks for your help!

---

edit:

Will also be possible to set a number of occurrences of some letter before?
Example: use "a" 11 times, the rest same as before?

Comment: I've got a feeling there's an x-y problem here. What exactly would you plan to do with the 89,718,834,605,400 results produced by your example and the concomitant ~17 petabytes of resources to store them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework fishing.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the numbers a bit:
Assume we have $n=3$ letters and $k=10$ places, and we have to use each letter at least once but no more than $m=5$ times.

(With your numbers `{n = 5, k = 20, m = 10}` I get a memory overflow.)

```
With[{n = 3, k = 10, m = 5},
  Join @@ Permutations /@
    Join @@@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1] &] /@
      Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[m]]]

(*    {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2},
       ...
       {3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}    *)
```

If you want letters, then at the end you can do

```
% /. {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}
```

Some explanations:

```
With[{n = 3, k = 10, m = 5},
  Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[m]]]
(*    {{5, 4, 1}, {5, 1, 4}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 1, 5}, {1, 5, 4},
       {1, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 2, 5},
       {2, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 4},
       {4, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 3, 4}}                          *)
```

gives all possible ways $\{n_a,n_b,n_c\}$ of choosing $n_a$ times the letter $a$, $n_b$ times the letter $b$, and $n_c$ times the letter $c$.

```
With[{n = 3, k = 10, m = 5},
  Join @@@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1] &] /@
    Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[m]]]
(*    {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}}    *)
```

converts these counts to actual sorted lists containing said numbers of characters, where $1$ stands for $a$, $2$ for $b$, and $3$ for $c$.

The remaining `Join @@ Permutations /@ ...` permutes each such list, to get the 44730 possible answers.

#### Edit

To be more specific about the constraints on the counts, you can use something like

```
{na, nb, nc} /. 
  Solve[{na + nb + nc == 10,
         1 <= na <= 5,
         3 <= nb <= 6, 
         2 <= nc <= 3},
        {na, nb, nc}, Integers]

(*    {{1, 6, 3}, {2, 5, 3}, {2, 6, 2}, {3, 4, 3},
       {3, 5, 2}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2}, {5, 3, 2}}    *)
```

to replace the `IntegerPartitions` of the simpler solution. Then, continue as before:

```
Join @@ Permutations /@ 
  Join @@@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1] &] /@ %

(*    {{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3},
       {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3},
       {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3},
       ...
       {3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}    *)
```